# Android Signing JKS Keystore is broken

Tags: java, android, android-studio, keystore, jks

I have published an app on the play store for over a year ago. Now when I'm trying to sign a new APK I'm receiving an error:

```
Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

Password validity:

- release.jks was stored in the CVS
- .jks password was stored on the CVS
- This is at least 5th release of the application

What I have done so far:

- I tried to find a password in the /Library/Logs/ - not found
- When I ented `keytool -list -v -keystore release.jks` I see information, but I'm not entering any password (leave empty)
- Didn' found a password in Gradle artifactory [logs](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-recover-a-lost-Android-signing-key-password)
- I generated a new keystore and was able to sign an app
- I have tried to impoty keystore `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore release.jks -destkeystore new.jks -deststoretype pkcs12`
- 'android', 'changeit' - doesn't work

  `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore release.jks -destkeystore new.jks -deststoretype pkcs12
  Importing keystore release.jks to new.jks...
  Enter destination keystore password:

  Re-enter new password: 
  Enter source keystore password:

  keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

Comment: the password is `android`

Comment: @AbdulmalekDery as I said - it isn't a new keystore. Anyway, I have already tried: 'android', 'changeit'. Doesn't work